# Hard coding URL parameters for reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a reverse proxy for one of my IP cameras so I can access it without passing basic credentials. The long URL for this is:

```
http://username:password@172.16.0.38/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1
```

The goal is to be able to hit `http://nginx-server:56700`.

My `nginx.conf` file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 56700;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.0.38/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic xxx";
        }
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

When I try to run it without the full parameterized URL, it only forwards to the IP, but I need to hard code the URL parameters. When I try the above config file, it doesn't load the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use rewrite in location blog

Comment: @l2ysho I'm sorry, what?